# linkchecker || running basic commands

Tags: python, linkchecker

This is absurd I'm going crazy here.. trying to run a simple command after installing the package (it's a crawler which crawls a given website url and returns all the links under the given parent url)
But no matter what I do I cant seem to get the most basic command running.

- Photo attached.
- Managed to install the package with the command: "pip install linkchecker".
- Don't understand the difference between pip and pip3.

And beside the point, why am I getting all of the other errors shown in the console??? **console output:**

```
In [1]: linkchecker http://www.example.com/ 
File "C:\Users\etain\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_46464/590413133.py", 
line 1
linkchecker http://www.example.com/
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

linkchecker website for general notes: https://linkchecker.github.io/linkchecker/index.html

Thank you everyone for helping out
[Screen Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv85T.jpg)

Comment: (a) your linked image shows an empty document, and (b) please don't post images of text -- include the code **in your question**, formatted as a code sample. Links can expire (or the content can change), rendering your question meaningless to future readers. Also, please try to limit yourself to a single question; there are several unrelated questions here, some of which may already have answers elsewhere on this site.

Comment: how do you mean? the screenshot shows the console outputs for different commands, I didn't write any special script cause I don't need to.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it was such a wide image. The point remains: we expect all the information necessary to the question to be included *in the question*.

Comment: edited the post

Answer (score 0):

The [basic usage](https://linkchecker.github.io/linkchecker/index.html#basic-usage) shown on the linked page...

```
$ linkchecker http://www.example.org/myhomepage/
```

...is showing you how to run the `linkchecker` command from a shell prompt (when you see lines in technical documentation beginning with `$` that is generally meant to indicate "type this at the shell prompt"). It looks as if you're working with some variant of IPython/Jupyter, which expects Python code.

Comment: I see, the environment is spyder (python 3.9). Any special command I need to run in order to switch to shell prompt?

Comment: Where did you run the `pip install` command necessary to install `linkchecker` in the first place? What editor/IDE are you working in right now?

Comment: I have run the command "pip install linkchecker" before taking the screenshot, When I tried to run it with pip3 it returned an error, so I tried without the "3" char and it run. Also I checked with "pip list", and it did install correctly